# cv:circle function draw multiple circles with a single call

Tags: c++, ios, ipad, opencv, objective-c++

I'm new with OpenCV library, and I would like to use it to detect circles in a video stream captured from an iPad's back camera. I figured out how to do it and with OpenCV 2.4.2, it can be done in less than 10 lines of code. But it doesn't work for me, and I think I missed something because of some weird behaviours I obtain.

The code is very simple and begins in the Objective-C callback triggers each time a new frame is captured by the camera. Here is what I do in this callback:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
       didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // Convert CMSampleBufferRef to CVImageBufferRef
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    // Lock pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);

    // Construct VideoFrame struct
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    size_t stride = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

    // Unlock pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    std::vector<unsigned char> data(baseAddress, baseAddress + (stride * height));

    // Call C++ function with these arguments => (data, (int)width, (int)height)
}
```

And here is the C++ function that process the image with OpenCV:

```
void proccessImage(std::vector<unsigned char>& imageData, int width, int height)
{
    // Create cv::Mat from std::vector<unsigned char>
    Mat src(width, height, CV_8UC4, const_cast<unsigned char*>(imageData.data()));
    Mat final;

    // Draw a circle at position (300, 200) with a radius of 30
    cv::Point center(300, 200);
    circle(src, center, 30.f, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);

    // Convert the gray image to RGBA
    cvtColor(src, final, CV_BGRA2RGBA);

    // Reform the std::vector from cv::Mat data
    std::vector<unsigned char> array;
    array.assign((unsigned char*)final.datastart, (unsigned char*)final.dataend);

    // Send final image data to GPU and draw it
}
```

The image retrieve from iPad's back camera is in BGRA (32 bits) format.

What I expected was an image from the iPad's back camera with a simple circle drawn at the position x = 300px, y = 200px and with a radius of 30px.

And this is what I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWfwa.jpg

Do you know what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I finally figured out what happen, and it's my entire fault...

When you create a new Mat you need to pass it the image's height as first argument, and not width. The circle is drawn properly if I switch the arguments.